# Server getting overloaded

Tags: mysql, tomcat, redhat

I have 2 setups tomcat5.5.20 on Redhat and mysql 4.1.22 on another Redhat server.

Recently my webserver started getting overloaded up to 80-90%.

After checking i found repeating errors(each seconds) in catalina.out. Can it cause the server overload or where else can be the root of the problem ?

catalina.out:

```
DBCP object created 2010-12-22 13:33:12 by the following code was never closed:
java.lang.Exception
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace.init(AbandonedTrace.java:96)
```

i have to restart tomcat once a day when server load reaches 80-90%. 
Also catalina.out file is growing too fast which every few hours need to clear the logs.

My datasource config:

> ```
>  <bean id="myDataSource"
>     class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
>     destroy-method="close">
>     <property name="driverClassName">
>         <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
>     </property>
> ```
>
> jdbc:mysql://XXX/XXX?autoReconnect=true
>           
>           
>               20
>           
>           
>               20

```
    <property name="maxIdle">
        <value>50</value>
    </property>

    <property name="maxActive">
        <value>50</value>
    </property>

    <property name="removeAbandoned">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout">
        <value>2400</value>
    </property> 
    <property name="username">
        <value>XXX</value>
    </property>  
    <property name="password">
        <value>XXX</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I have sufficient information to really evaluate your circumstance, but given what you have provided, I give you the following guess: change false to true.

```
    <property name="removeAbandoned">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
```

I imagine your code is opening things and then not closing them before ending.

Comment: seems it fixed the issue, now the server load is normal. thanks a lot.